# URLSession retry connection on fallback with inner callback

Tags: ios, swift, urlsession

I made a function which makes a network call but I want to do it more efficient with retrying network call on fallback status.

```
func dataTaskFunction(completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> ()) { 
   var tryCount: Int = 0
   
   innerDataTask(url) { (data, error) in
      tryCount += 1
      guard error == nil else { 
         completionHandler(false)
         // retry network call until 3
         if tryCount < 3 { 
            // make innerDataTask again..
         }
         
         return
      }
      completionHandler(true)
   }  
}
```

The function handles data tasks and they have `completionHandler` both. When I try to retrying the data task again it seems an inner call inside a call and I would like to learn how can I do it without callback hell like a waterfall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you could call `dataTaskFunction` recursively. The counter variable must be declared outside of the function

```
var tryCount = 0

func dataTaskFunction(completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> ()) { 
   
   innerDataTask(url) { (data, error) in
      tryCount += 1
      guard error == nil else { 
         // retry network call until 3
         if tryCount < 3 { 
            self.dataTaskFunction(completionHandler: completionHandler)
         } else {
            completionHandler(false)
         }
         return
      }
      completionHandler(true)
   }  
}
```